# Doing Dawah in non-Muslim countries

Tags: non-muslim, dawah

I would like to ask a question in two parts. Firstly I would like to ask is it obligatory on Muslims who live in non-Muslim countries to do dawah. I have heard that a Muslim cannot migrate to a non-Muslim country for worldly gain, but for either Jihad or Dawah (which is a type of Jihad). But it seems to me that the majority of Muslims come to non-Muslim counties for setting up a business, a job, easier life etc...

If this is the case the second part of the question is that, do these Muslims preach to  non-Muslims of this non-Muslims country. I ask this question because it does not seem logical that Muslims should come to a non-Muslim country to preach to only Muslims, this then begs the question why have they come to a non-Muslim country anyway. Imagine that a group of Muslims come to a non-Muslim country and these are the first Muslims there and they decided to preach only themselves.

Every time I go to mosque, I notice that 100% of the people are immigrates from other Muslim countries, most of them are not engaged in preaching but running after worldly things, and this is the probably the reason why in this (UK) non-Muslim country where the majority of people are non-Muslim (95%) the mosques only has people who have immigrated to this non-Muslim country as the immigrates who came here did not come here to propagate the religion but to only make money and live an easy life. The second question I asked because I have noticed that the majority of Muslims that are engaged in Dawah do this strictly only to Muslims and I what to know if they are fulfilling this right of Dawah in a non-Muslim country by preaching only to Muslims. Yes its true we also need to preach Muslims in this non-Muslim country, even if our initial intentions were not correct i.e for worldly gain and only preach ourselves, there are some families here that have lived 4 or more generations in England, but in a non-Muslim country to say preach only Muslims, to me it just seems better if you just all move back to Muslim countries, that seems more logical. Because in the grand schemes of things if you think about it, why then are you in a non-Muslim country. A way to understand this is, imagine all the Muslims in England moved to a Muslim country, would it make any difference to the Muslims or non-Muslims of the country they moved from. Lets not look at the worldly economic side to this but in terms of our faith and islam. Although I have expressed my opinion here, these questions need to be seriously addressed as it represent an issue relating to the majority of Muslims in non-Muslim countries.

Comment: It is disliked or even haram to stay in non-Muslim countries, if one is not able to live there as a Muslim (one has a weak iman or knowledge about Islam and would easily loose his faith), if there's no safety for a Muslim in this Country, if there's no benefit in this travel (Such a benefit can be a worldly benefit for example Business, work or studies). Also note that Muslims are asked to abide to contracts and if the law in the land is against preaching the matter may have legal consequences. Al-Albani say it is haram to stay there unless for business [4:97](https://legacy.quran.com/4/97).

Comment: You should consider splitting this into reasonably answerable questions. Also read [this post](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions?s=1|27.4362) in our Meta.

Comment: I don't think this commit section is a place for debate, but I don't know how Al-Albani (may Allah grant him paradise) came with the conclusion that verse 4:97 means that you can stay in non-Muslim countries for business, it seem off topic. This verse is talking about people who have become mixed in with wrong doing, or doing injustice, were they are they consider themselves to be weaker minority so say they are oppressed so cannot oppose the majority involved in the crime but they can migrate from the crime but do not.

Comment: Just to clarify: I've mixed the Information to some extent due to the character-limitation of the comment section: Sheikh al-Albani is basically against staying in non-Muslim land and consider it is haram based on that verse where he considers the question: "Was not the earth of Allah spacious [enough] for you to emigrate therein?" as addressing people who seek refuge there. He allows business trips because the sahaba used to travel to the roman empire for their business.